# @types/react-transition-group: Generic type 'ReactElement<P, T>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.ts(2707)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-transition-group

I've just got hit with this one.

Turns out that in the file `node_modules/@types/react-transition-group/TransitionGroup.d.ts`

There is this type:

```
  type TransitionGroupProps<T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements = "div", V extends ReactType = any> =
        (IntrinsicTransitionGroupProps<T> & JSX.IntrinsicElements[T]) | (ComponentTransitionGroupProps<V>) & {
        children?: ReactElement<TransitionProps> | Array<ReactElement<TransitionProps>>;
        childFactory?(child: ReactElement): ReactElement;
        [prop: string]: any;
    };
```

And this is making the compilation fail with this error:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-transition-group/TransitionGroup.d.ts:16:30 
    TS2707: Generic type 'ReactElement<P, T>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-transition-group/TransitionGroup.d.ts:16:45 
    TS2707: Generic type 'ReactElement<P, T>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.
```

I've found that if I replace this:

```
childFactory?(child: ReactElement): ReactElement;
```

for this:

```
childFactory?(child: ReactElement<any, any>): ReactElement<any, any>;
```

But this is not the real solution, or problem I think...

How should I fix this?

Comment: Running into something very similar with@types/react-select 2.0.17 (see my other post on that). Was able to fix that by downgrading to a lower version (2.0.8). thru trial and error. However, react-select depends on @types/react-transition-group (at version "*") and now stuck with this error.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [this commit](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/commit/1a07ffda4e635247dc2e9b7613cd252724a0216a#diff-94b8dd3813924ed6dd4885e530f4bfb9) removed all the template values and caused the break. I was able to resolve this by explicitly adding a version (2.0.15) to the package.

`npm install @types/react-transition-group@2.0.15`

2.0.15 is the latest that works. 2.0.16 and newer contains the bad commit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and there is an eerily similar [issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/33065) reported just now for a `@types/recompose` module. As a temporary fix I uninstalled `@types/react-transition-group` and added a `types/react-transition-group.d.ts` file at the root of my project with the following:

```js
declare module 'react-transition-group' {
    export const CSSTransitionGroup: any
}
```

At least then you aren't changing stuff from the `node_modules` folder. 
I'm using v1 of `react-transition-group`  so your placeholder definition might look a little different. Of course you'll loose all type-hinting you don't provide yourself, so it might be and idea to give the GitHub repo a heads up as well so they can provide a fix, should the `recompose` issue not be relevant.

Comment: I have run into the same issue and forked the DefinatelyTyped repo (source of @types/react-transition-group) and fixed as above. Problem is if I try to run their tests it fails with "This is the default value for this type parameter, so it can be omitted." So it's "damned if I do, damned if I dont." lol